# Why do some Java setter methods automatically become Kotlin properties but some don't?

Tags: android, properties, kotlin, kotlin-interop

e.g. this [WebSettings](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html) Java class.

It has a Java method `setJavaScriptEnabled(boolean)` that turns into a Kotlin property `javaScriptEnabled` as below, but there is also `setSupportZoom(boolean)` that does not turn into a Kotlin property `supportZoom`.

```
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        settings.setSupportZoom(false)
        settings.builtInZoomControls = false
        settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters):

> `Boolean` accessor methods (where the name of the getter starts with `is` and the name of the setter starts with `set`) are represented as properties which have the same name as the getter method.

And still as of Kotlin 1.2.0:

> Note that, if the Java class only has a setter, it will not be visible as a property in Kotlin, because Kotlin does not support set-only properties at this time.

There is no method in the Java class of signature `boolean isSupportMultipleWindows()` and [`boolean supportMultipleWindows()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#supportMultipleWindows()) does not match the property representation in Kotlin.